# Disabled button working in my View page using jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my Beginform and I have buttons in my view..

On document load I am doing disabling my submit button

I am seeing My buttons are Disabled but when I click on Save button still its going to my controler?

please can anybody tell me why its doing like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `click` event still fires on the disabled buttons.

If you can influence the functions that fire, you could do a `disabled` check in them and `return false` if the button is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use an input of `type='button'` instead and do a check in the jquery click function of the button to see if it is disabled and submit the form if not. You could also pass a value into a hidden field in order to know what button has been clicked at the controller.

```
<input type='hidden' id='hdnSave' name='Save' />


$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
if ($('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled') == false)
{
$('#hdnSave').val('Save');
$('#exc-').submit();
}
});
```